# is there a numeric Qt edit box with more than one spinner?

Tags: qt

Before i embark on developing a custom control i wonder if somebody would know of a QT control consisting of an edit box (for a number) with more than one spinner next to it.  One spinner would be used to increment/decrement the number by 10's, the other by 1's.  Ideally, one could allow even three spinners (for the 100's).

There is no standalone spinner but i'm thinking maybe putting several small scrollbar controls next to each other would do.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that there is such a control.

Note however that a default `QSpinBox` supports incrementing/decrementing in steps of 10 by pressing the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip!

I ended up creating a horizontal layout with 0 spacing, then placing three QDoubleSpinBox instances in it.  On the second and third i set the max width to 15 to just show the spinners.  Visually it looked great: an edit box with three spinners.

I then connected the value changed signal from the first to the second and third and the value changed from the second and third to the first.  So then clicking on any of the spinners changed the value on the first correctly.  Finally, i adjusted the stepsize on the spinners as needed.

It was a lot easier than what i thought it would be.